# The entity or complex type 'AdventureWorks2012Model.Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

As you can see, I got this error when I built Data Gird using Kendo UI. Does anybody could point out where I'm wrong in my code below.

```
 private IEnumerable<Product> GetSubProduct()
         {
             var context = new AdvenDBEntities();
             var subcate = context.Products.Select(p => new Product
             {
                 ProductID = p.ProductID,
                 Name = p.Name,
                 Color = p.Color,
                 ListPrice = p.ListPrice,
             }).ToList();

            return subcate;
          }
```

Error:
`The entity or complex type 'AdventureWorks2012Model.Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`
Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Probably the `Product` is an entity in model, try creating anonymous type object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Product` is an entity of model, you are creating new object of this entity while selecting the records, which is NOT good idea, I am NOT sure how model will handle this kind of behaviour that is why it is preventing you to do so, (I guess). Anyway you can change the code to this,

```
private IEnumerable<Product> GetSubProduct()
{
    var context = new AdvenDBEntities();
    var subcate = context.Products.ToList();

    return subcate;
}
```

BTW your function name indicating that you are missing a `Where` clause.

Also you can create some custom DTO class and use it instead.

E.g.

```
class ProductDTO
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<ProductDTO> GetSubProduct()
{
    var context = new AdvenDBEntities();
    var subcate = context.Products.Select(p => new ProductDTO
                        {
                            ProductID = p.ProductID,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            Color = p.Color,
                            ListPrice = p.ListPrice,
                        }).ToList();

    return subcate;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, I missed create a new ViewModel `ProductDTO` that you just mentioned about. Thanks, @sallushan!

Answer (score 0):

The first bad smell code I can point out for you. **DBContext** implements **IDisposable** so you are responsible for calling **Dispose** on it. In all, but one case in here, ***using block***

You must build query to get all the product and then extract from it.

```
private IEnumerable<Product> GetSubProduct()
{
         using (var context = new AdvenDBEntities())
         {
              // Get all constructed type product and then select from it
              var subcate = context.Products
               .ToList()       
               .Select(p => new Product
               {
                 ProductID = p.ProductID,
                 Name = p.Name,
                 Color = p.Color,
                 ListPrice = p.ListPrice,
               });

              return subcate;
        }
 }
```